# How can I mount a side-mount light onto a top-mount area?

Tags: electrical, lighting, exterior

I have an existing light on top of a retaining wall:

[image]

I found some light fixtures that I will be using everywhere else around the house, but they are side/wall mount:

[image]

Is there some way for me to mount my side-mount lights onto the top-mount place? I tried to find a small lamp post that'll accommodate this, but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Voting to close as overly broad or open-ended. You're essentially asking how to make a horizontal surface vertical (without qualification), or how to dramatically modify a UL-listed light fixture. Neither are great questions for our format.

Comment: And the 2nd option is highly **NOT** recommended. Your best bet is to find bottom-mount lights that match your wall mount lights as closely as you're willing to accept.

Comment: If you convert it to 12v then you can mod it however you want; still not sure why people insist on using mains for outdoor lighting...

Comment: What all do you need the fixture to light? (all 360deg around it, or is having a shadow OK?)

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to replace the mount plate and tubular arm with a custom assembly of black iron pipe and fittings that acts as a stand. From bottom up...

- A 3/4" or 1" floor flange (whatever is large enough to cover the junction box)
- A vertical pipe of ~18"
- A 90° elbow to horizontal
- A pipe nipple of ~8"
- A 90° elbow to vertical (downward)
- A short pipe nipple through the fixture's top cap
- A nut or end cap with a hole drilled for the wires

---

```
    =========
   ||        ||
   ||        ||
   ||      _/  \_    
   ||     |      |
   ||     |      |
   ||     |      |
   ||     |______|
   ||     
 __||__
```

Be sure to protect the wiring so it isn't damaged on the pipe fitting edges. Maybe use a length of exterior extension cord between the junction box and the light housing.

Comment: I have had customers try to save $ on fixtures and ended up doing exactly what Isherwood has sketched. By the time it was done and the mount the fixture cost was close to double and they looked cheaply done to me it really looked DIY even though professionally wired. Remember the j box below has to be accessible that makes columns of concrete or brick look worse. The look the owners liked the best was conduit using a 180 degree long sweep. No fittings except the box / access I did not expect them to last but last time I was up there they were still standing 5-6 years later. No extension cord.

Comment: This looks like it's hanging - I need to mount directly to the side of the pole somehow, no?

Comment: Either you don't understand my suggestion or I don't understand your criteria. Yes, it would hang, just as it does from the factory.